# Android SDK Manager not showing in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio

I'm trying to follow this guide to install Visual Studio with the Android SDK manager:
Link to guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows

So I downloaded Visual Studio from here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
After installation, the menu `Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager` is not available.

What should be done to make the menu available? And be able to open the Android SDK Manager?

Answer (score 0):

using Visual Studio 2019:

You will need to run the "Visual Studio Installer" again. Then click modify, and in the Workloads tab, select:

Mobile development with .NET.
Build cross-platform applications for iOS, Android or Windows using Xamarin

The Android SDK manager will be available after you've installed this workload.

Answer (score -2):

You could try to run VS as an administrator, which resolves almost any issue of the kind you are experiencing right now.

Another free advice before you start: if you find any problem building(even when you start VS as admin), first try to delete your \bin and \obj folders and try again. That is the solution to 99% of the issues.